# How to check substring in Room DB android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

In Room SQLite database in android

if we have `tags` column with value `1023652, 2154781, 1154230`

how to write a query that check whether `tags` contains the value `1023652, 1154230`, which in this case the first and last value of the `tags` value. But in runtime, the passed string may contains values in any part of the string.

Usecase, I have a column called `tags` which is a list of strings stored in room DB as `TEXT` primary type
and during runtime I wanna dynamically pass a list of strings and find all rows where `tags` column contains all of strings passed as argument?

I have tried a query like  `@Query("SELECT * from ContactInfo WHERE ContactInfo.tags LIKE :argumentTagsString")`

I expected to return all the rows where `tags` column contains `argumentTagsString` but it returned empty list

Comment: Take some time to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Answer (score 0):

you can use like for each of the tags

```
SELECT * from ContactInfo WHERE 
ContactInfo.tags LIKE '%1023652%' AND 
ContactInfo.tags LIKE '%1154230%'
```

with room

```
    @Dao
    interface ContactInfoDao {
    
        @Query("SELECT * from ContactInfo WHERE (:tag1 IS NULL OR ContactInfo.tags LIKE :tag1) AND (:tag2 IS NULL OR ContactInfo.tags LIKE :tag2) AND ... ")
        fun searchByTags(tag1: String?, tag2: String?, ...): List<ContactInfo>
    }
 and call

    val results = contactInfoDao.searchByTags("%1023652%", "%1154230%", ...)

update for list of strings

@Dao
interface ContactInfoDao {

    @Transaction
    fun searchByTags(tags: List<String?>): List<ContactInfo> {
        // Start the SQL statement
        var sql = "SELECT * from ContactInfo WHERE "

        // Build the WHERE clause
        val conditions = tags.map { "(:tag IS NULL OR ContactInfo.tags LIKE :tag)" }
        sql += conditions.joinToString(separator = " AND ")

        // Use the Rooms simple query method
        return SimpleSQLiteQuery(sql, tags.toTypedArray()).let { 
            queryByTags(it)
        }
    }

    @RawQuery
    fun queryByTags(query: SimpleSQLiteQuery): List<ContactInfo>
}
```

Comment: thanks for you answer, but I don't now the number of arguments at the compile time as what is passed is a string that converted from a list

Comment: you can send a list of strings, take a look at the updated answer